# Pinyin Character entry on a touchscreen keyboard

Tags: wpf, touchscreen

The app I'm developing requires that it be deployed in China, which means that it needs to have Pinyin and Chinese character handling.  I'm told that the way that our customers handle character entry is like so:

- Enter in the pinyin character, like 'zhang'
- As they enter the characters, a list of possible Chinese (Mandarin?) characters are presented to the user, like:

[image: pinyin characters]

- The user will then select '1' to enter the family name that is roughly translated to 'zhang'

How can I hook such programs (I believe one is called 'mspy.exe', from Microsoft, which I'm lead to believe comes with Microsoft versions of XP) into a WPF text box?  Right now, the user can enter text either by using their keyboard or by using an on-screen keyboard, so I will probably need to capture the event of a keypress from either source and feed it to some OS event or to MSPY.exe or some similar program.

Or is there some other way to enter pinyin and have it converted to Mandarin?  Is there a program other than MSPY I should look at?

EDIT: For those of you who think that this should 'just work', it does not.  Chinese character entry will work just fine if entering text into notepad or the start->run menu or whatever, but it will not work in WPF.  That's the key to this question: how do I enable WPF entry?  There's the Google Pinyin and Sogou pinyin, but the websites are in Mandarin or Chinese or something similar and I don't read the language.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood the system will handle this automagically if a Chinese input method is selected by the user. Trying to implement your own system for dealing with Chinese text is probably a bad idea.

Be sure to test it on a Chinese version of XP before deploying, of course, but with any amount of decent design in WPF, and XP as a whole, at all; it should Just Work.

Comment: But it doesn't, which is why I'm posting the question.

Comment: Even with the language set to Chinese?

Comment: Even with the language set to Chinese, yes.  And with the 'extend support of advanced text services to all programs' option turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but as far as I know, this is handled by the operating system, and I'm not sure that application really have that much control over it.

Here's a guide on how you enable pin yin Chinese character entry in Windows XP:

- http://www.biblioscape.com/tips/tip_020318.htm

Comment: That's actually a guide for Windows 2000-- Windows XP has the language bar, which makes this kind of language selection much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

My application works with chinese input, and it is using WPF, i don't get what you want to ask.
You can input chinese text in a WPF textbox using sogou pinyin, or microsoft pinyin. Tested in xp and win7

It is just because your ime is setted to input in english.
Press shift once briefly if using sogou pinyin and you will see the hanzi of "yi" become "zhong"
At that point you will be able to type in chinese ;-)

Also, there are IME property on textboxes, select to have it On, otherwise the IME will be in "english mode"